# ionic3, differences between NavController and Nav, from package 'ionic-angular'

Tags: ionic3

in ionic doc link i have NavController:

https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/navigation/NavController/

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
   template: '<ion-nav #myNav [root]="rootPage"></ion-nav>'
})
export class MyApp {
   @ViewChild('myNav') nav: NavController
```

and in my ionic3 project installing with 'ionic start myionic3' with template 'super' the app.component.ts have:

```
...
import { Platform, Nav, Config } from 'ionic-angular';
...
export class MyApp {
  public rootPage: any = LoginPage;

  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;
...
```

why there are differents, ionic doc site is outdated ?

Comment: I can't answer why docs are out of date, but I found this [guys YouTube video][1] helpful for this. He's got quite a useful channel for Ionic 3.
He didn't use blank template, but a tabs page, and involved things like @IonicPage and lazy loaded pages. So that explains the rootPage part. But doesn't explain Nav vs NavController admittedly.

  [1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J3pi2ju2gCM

Answer (score 0):

Looking a the source on Github, from a cursory glance it appears that [Nav](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/components/nav/nav.ts) is a remapping of the NavController.
[Config](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/blob/master/src/config/config.ts) has a lot of comments to describe properties.
I would have expected something on their blog about it.. Maybe it's imminent..

**Update:**
Documentation now seems to exist:
See [Nav](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/nav/Nav/) and [Config](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/config/Config/)